# How mpesa ssl handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl

With the mpesa B2C integration. am trying to use Curl

```
        $url = "https://196.201.214.136:18423/mminterface/request";




    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 18423);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                           'Content-type: text/xml', 
                                           'Content-length: ' . strlen($requestXml)
                                         ));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    } else{
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

**I get an error**

> error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure'

This is after changing ssl version from nss to openssl.
How do I solve the handshake failure.

Comment: The client and server could not agree on an SSL/TLS version or a cipher suite. Check which protocols and  cipher suites the server supports, and which the client supports.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, MPESA uses some public-private key pairs that you need to generate in conjunction with them. If you don't have those set up right, your SSL requests will fail. Have you done this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Safaricom has released M-Pesa APIs as RESTful APIs accessible through their [developer portal](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke) . You need not have SSL certificates signed by Safaricom in order to consume the APIs. As long as your server has a publicly signed certificate, the Safaricom API Gateway should be able to receive requests and send responses to your server.